# Angular ApexCharts - Transform data to display as bar chart

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I have used [ApexCharts](https://apexcharts.com/) in my Angular 16 application.

Here my response is not appending on the chart. Please help me to modify the API response.

**Response from API:**

```
let data = [
  {
    tenantName: 'OBC+',
    labelName: 'Application',
    total: 85,
    postiveTotal: '21',
    negativeTotal: '64',
  },
  {
    tenantName: 'Discovery-world',
    labelName: 'Application',
    total: 194,
    postiveTotal: '119',
    negativeTotal: '75',
  },
  {
    tenantName: 'OBC+',
    labelName: 'Channels',
    total: 40,
    postiveTotal: '0',
    negativeTotal: '40',
  },
  {
    tenantName: 'Discovery-world',
    labelName: 'Channels',
    total: 59,
    postiveTotal: '0',
    negativeTotal: '59',
  },
];
```

I need to modify my response with this format.

**Expected Format**:

```
this.stackedChartData = [
  {
    name: 'OBC Postivie',
    group: 'OBC',
    data: [21, 0],
  },
  {
    name: 'OBC Negative',
    group: 'OBC',
    data: [64, 40],
  },
  {
    name: 'Discovery-world Postivie',
    group: 'Discovery-world',
    data: [119, 0],
  },
  {
    name: 'Discovery-world Negative',
    group: 'Discovery-world',
    data: [75, 59],
  },
];
```

I have tried with this code but it is not working properly.

```
let labels = [...new Set(data.map((x: any) => x.labelName))];
let subLabels = data.reduce((acc, cur: any) => {
  if (
    acc.findIndex(
      (x) =>
        //console.log(x)
        x.tenantName == cur.tenantName && x.labelName == cur.labelName
    ) == -1
  )
    acc.push({
      tenantName: cur.tenantName,
      labelName: cur.labelName,
      postiveTotal: cur.postiveTotal,
      negativeTotal: cur.negativeTotal,
    });

  return acc;
}, [] as { tenantName: string; labelName: string; postiveTotal: number; negativeTotal: number }[]);

console.log(subLabels);
```

I am going to try `postiveTotal`, `negativeTotal` with group of labelName.

This is my chart demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gswyat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

Comment: Hi, I am a bit not understand your expected data for the `data`. Why the OBC values are 44, 55? Can you provide the formula or actual value for the result?

Comment: Hi @YongShun I have updated the code please check. There is no formula behind.  I just try to take postiveTotal and negativeTotal with group of labelName.

Ex: labelName: 'Application',  postiveTotal = 21 and negativeTotal = 54

Please ceck in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gswyat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-agtkqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). But I feel that your desired data is incorrect for the graph: 1. The `stackChartLabels` (`['Application', 'Cusromer Care']`) is not relevant as the x-axis category. 2. If I change the `stackChartLabels` to `['OBC', 'Discovery-world']`, the some bars will show in wrong position.

Comment: Hi @YongShun
this is the one I expected please post your code I will upvote for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right way to iterate and transform the array via `.reduce()`.

Changes that you need:

1. The result of the array should be in `{ group: string; name: string; data: number[] }[]` type.
2. Check the `group` whether it was inserted previously. If not inserted, you should add two objects with "Positive" and "Negative".
3. If the `group` is inserted previously, get the objects by `group` and `name` and add the value into `data` array in the object.

```
let subLabels = data.reduce((acc, cur: any) => {
  if (
    acc.findIndex(
      (x) =>
        x.group == cur.tenantName
    ) == -1
  ) {
    acc.push({
      group: cur.tenantName,
      name: cur.tenantName + ' Positive',
      data: [Number(cur.postiveTotal)],
    });

    acc.push({
      group: cur.tenantName,
      name: cur.tenantName + ' Negative',
      data: [Number(cur.negativeTotal)],
    });
  } else {
    let groupPositive = acc.find(
      (x) =>
        x.group == cur.tenantName && x.name == cur.tenantName + ' Positive'
    );

    groupPositive.data.push(Number(cur.postiveTotal));

    let groupNegative = acc.find(
      (x) =>
        x.group == cur.tenantName && x.name == cur.tenantName + ' Negative'
    );

    groupNegative.data.push(Number(cur.negativeTotal));
  }

  return acc;
}, [] as { group: string; name: string; data: number[] }[]);

this.stackedChartData = subLabels;
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-agtkqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)